# Is there a V speed for the point an aircraft starts an ascent at 0 angle of attack?

Tags: lift, v-speeds

Some aircraft with an angle of incidence or cambered airfoils are capable of climb without any angle of attack, Is there a V speed for the speed at which an aircraft starts a positive climb?

Comment: I'd like to point out that aircraft with an angle of incidence does not equate to zero angle of attack.  It means that the wing will have a positive angle of attack when the fuselage is aligned with the relative wind.  Regarding your question:  I will let the engineers answer, but yes, if a wing is capable of producing lift at zero angle of attack it will obviously start climbing once it attains a certain speed...  Are you asking how to calculate this?

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no V-Speed associated with zero angle of attack, nor is climb associated with angle of attack. Since zero angle of attack does not directly translate to minimum drag for a *production aircraft* in operation, it is not a meaningful performance gate, which is what V-Speeds are designed to represent.

However, this is not to say that having a zero flow incidence against the fuselage is not desirable:

1. If the body-axis is aligned with the fuselage longitudinal axis, it would be desirable from a passenger comfort standpoint to fly at zero AOA during level cruise. We don't want to have an inclined martini glass for the whole duration of the flight.
2. Non-zero flow incidence against the fuselage does create drag. It would be desirable from a performance perspective to decrease any form of drag during cruise or climb.

This is achieved during aircraft design. The wing setting angle against the fuselage is tuned such that the *average* operational flow incidence angle against the fuselage is minimized.

Comment: My apologies, I'm confused, My question was for if there was a V-Speed Indicating the aircraft speed at where the lift force would be equal to weight at a zero angle of attack, such as a "Level flight" speed. (Of course, very dependent on the current weight of the aircraft such as fuel level and passengers aboard)

Comment: "Vtos" Is the minimum speed for climb with one engine operative, But what about in normal function? I was thinking vlof, but that does depend on angle of attack due to rotation on takeoff.

Comment: @James The question is, why do you want to lift off at zero AOA? What's special about zero AOA? If you have a tricycle, being able to rotate allows you to decrease the drag during ground roll, which increases field performance.

Comment: general aviation question for me honestly, What about a cruise/level flight where you want to be as level as possible without a change in pitch? ( I understand on my airplanes this requires a 1-2 degree nose up attitude )